# nodejs getting xml returning nothing

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I am trying to download an xml file so I can parse it in nodejs. Here is the test I built via mocha, the test passes but nothing is showing up on the console. What am I doing wrong?

```
it('Get XML data', function() {
var options = {
      hostname: 'stona-app01.us.work.net',
      port: 1213,
      path: '/solrLive/STONA-STOUS-product-search-idx-en_US/select/?version=2.2&start=2&rows=2&qf=SKU&fl=*&indent=on&onlineFlag=1',
      method: 'POST'
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
      });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
    });
});
```

The URL in the code is not reachable so you will not be able to test it.

Answer (score 0):

Your test is asynchronous, so you must define your test to take a `done` parameter and call it when your test is done:

```
it('Get XML data', function (done) {
   var options = {
      hostname: 'stona-app01.us.work.net',
      port: 1213,
      path: '/solrLive/STONA-STOUS-product-search-idx-en_US/select/?version=2.2&start=2&rows=2&qf=SKU&fl=*&indent=on&onlineFlag=1',
      method: 'POST'
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function(res) {
      console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
        done(); // We're done!
      });
    });

    req.on('error', function(e) {
      console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
      done(e); // Pass the error to Mocha.
    });
});
```

Comment: Adding the code above did not fix the problem. Here is my console ➜  new-age-automation git:(master) ✗ mocha tests/unittests


  Test all the custom functions
    ✓ Generate email address 
    ✓ Get XML data 


  2 passing (7ms)

➜  new-age-automation git:(master) ✗

Comment: Could it be because the the link is to a page that is xml and not actually calling a .xml file?